# El plugin Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core no funciona en mi proyecto Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Estoy siguiendo los pasos de instalación del SDK de Firebase.

Todos los pasos se siguieron al pie de la letra pero **Firebase no establece comunicación con la App para verificar la correcta instalación del SDK**, el código siguiente se agregó a la clase AppDelegate:

```
Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intenté con todas las versiones (disponibles para Xamarin) del Plugin Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core y el resultado es el mismo.